# Some help scraping a page in Java

Tags: java, html, xhtml, screen-scraping

I need to scrape a web page using Java and I've read that regex is a pretty inefficient way of doing it and one should put it into a DOM Document to navigate it.

I've tried reading the documentation but it seems too extensive and I don't know where to begin.

Could you show me how to scrape [this](http://www.cs.grinnell.edu/~walker/fluency-book/labs/sample-table.html) table in to an array? I can try figuring out my way from there.  A snippet/example would do just fine too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [jsoup: Java HTML Parser](http://jsoup.org/). It is an excellent library with good sample codes.

Comment: I had a look at the jSoup docs and it looks pretty darn good. I was looking for something on the lines of BeautifulSoup for Python and here it is!

Answer (score 4):

1. **Transform** the web page you are trying to scrap into an **XHTML** document. There are several options to do this with Java, such as **[JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/index.html)** and **[HTMLCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php)**. These tools will also automatically fix malformed HTML (e.g., close unclosed tags). Both work very well, but I prefer JTidy because it integrates better with Java's DOM API;
2. **Extract** required information using [**XPath**](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) expressions.

Here is a working example using JTidy and the Web Page you provided, used to extract all file names from the table.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create a new JTidy instance and set options
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setXHTML(true); 

    // Parse an HTML page into a DOM document
    URL url = new URL("http://www.cs.grinnell.edu/~walker/fluency-book/labs/sample-table.html");        
    Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(url.openStream(), System.out);

    // Use XPath to obtain whatever you want from the (X)HTML
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//td[@valign = 'top']/a/text()");
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        filenames.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
    }

    System.out.println(filenames);
}
```

The result will be `[Integer Processing:, Image Processing:, A Photo Album:, Run-time Experiments:, More Run-time Experiments:]` as expected.

Another cool tool that you can use is [`Web Harvest`](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/index.php). It basically does everything I did above but using an XML file to configure the extraction pipeline.

Comment: This is an elegant solution but overkill for some simple scraping. Building a dom of a large web page will be quite slow (the original example was a small page, but in general most web pages these days have complicated DOMs).

Answer (score 0):

Regex is definitely the way to go. Building a DOM is overly complicated and itself requires a lot of text parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is scraping a table into a datafile, regex will be just fine, and may be even better than using a DOM document.  DOM documents will use up a lot of memory (especially for really large data tables) so you probably want a SAX parser for large documents.