# Looking for a simple Java spider

Tags: java, web-scraping

I need to supply a base URL (such as `http://www.wired.com`) and need to spider through the entire site outputting an array of pages (off the base URL). Is there any library that would do the trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used [`Web Harvest`](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/) a couple of times, and it is quite good for web scraping.

> Web-Harvest is Open Source Web Data
>   Extraction tool written in Java. It
>   offers a way to collect desired Web
>   pages and extract useful data from
>   them. In order to do that, it
>   leverages well established techniques
>   and technologies for text/xml
>   manipulation such as XSLT, XQuery and
>   Regular Expressions. Web-Harvest
>   mainly focuses on HTML/XML based web
>   sites which still make vast majority
>   of the Web content. On the other hand,
>   it could be easily supplemented by
>   custom Java libraries in order to
>   augment its extraction capabilities.

Alternatively, you can roll your own web scraper using tools such as `JTidy` to first convert an HTML document to XHTML, and then processing the information you need with `XPath`. For example, a **very** naïve XPath expression to extract all hyperlinks from `http://www.wired.com`, would be something like `//a[contains(@href,'wired')]/@href`. You can find some sample code for this approach in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576822/some-help-scraping-a-page-in-java/4576834#4576834) to a similar question.

Comment: Thanks for this resource. I was able to adapt it successfully. However, if a webpage response results in a 500, the scraper fails (for  instance - http://www.allure.com/magazine/flipbook) outputting a "An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document."  Any thoughts on this error message?

Answer (score 2):

'Simple' is perhaps not a relevant concept here. it's a complex task. I recommend [nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/).