# How to get list of files that are located in Apache Server and display the list in an android activity page?

Tags: android

I tried the code below...

```
String file_path="http://localhost:8080/HellowJSP/Files";
File[] fileNameList;

//inside On Create()
File f=new File(file_path);
fileNameList=f.listFiles();
String[] filelist=new String[fileNameList.length];

for(i=0;i<fileNameList.length;i++){
         filelist[i]=fileNameList[i].getName();
}
```

But I got a `NullPointerException`. The variable `fileNameList results a null value`. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Add complete stack trace

Comment: You cannot directly convert a url into a File object. Refer this post to get an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165732/java-read-in-text-files-from-a-directory-from-the-internet

Comment: Thank you.... I tried getPath() function to convert the url to File object... but i face the same problem. again fileNameList results a null value.