# Calling a script from a certain URL in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, html, parsing, execute

I'm using Java to parse HTML from a random website, let's say it's http://google.com for convenience. After parsing the HTML data, I want to extract some of that data, and show it on a display. After that the user will get to input a search term, and  press a button.  This button will execute that script behind the "search" button. I want to do this with several sites, so giving me a way that only works with google won't help me a lot.

Comment: So what if the button makes an AJAX call? - you'll run into the Same Origin Policy and it will break because the page expects to be on domain X and it's now proxied into domain Y.

Comment: I don't understand the question. A website has html--what does google vs. ?? have to do with the html from the website? How does what you display differ from, say, "view source"?

Comment: I think he wants to show screen-scraped pages and have them behave as original pages.

Comment: Yes, like diodeus said, but I want to be able to use scripts on that page. Like the Google search button, or the the stackoverflow vote button. For example, that I press a button in my own program that will actually click a vote button on this site (by executing the code behind that button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit:*

Ah, I see.   You are asking about how to call a remote web-page from your code?  There are a couple of ways you can do this:

- You can do it "by-hand" using the [Java `URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class.
- You could use the great [Apache HTTPClient library](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).
- Another possibility is a tool like [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

---

Scraping of websites is a difficult problem and rarely have I found that a single scraper can handle multiple websites.  The idea of a generic scraper is just not possible.

I would recommend writing a Java `interface` which is something like `HandleSearchPage`.  It would contain a method to scrap the page and extract some of the data and another method to submit a search.

Then you can implement your scrapers for Google, Yahoo, etc..  As to how to parse html and drive a webpage there are many other questions/answers on that specific topic.

- [Some help scraping a page in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576822/some-help-scraping-a-page-in-java)
- [Trying to parse links in an HTML directory listing using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875867/trying-to-parse-links-in-an-html-directory-listing-using-java)

Best of luck.

Comment: Oh nonononono my bad, what I meant was, I need an explanation that will make me able to do it for all sites I find, programmatically of course. I absolutely don´t expect a single java code to be able to manipulate all scripts on every website haha. I just don´t want you to give me an explanation that I will only be able to use for google.com. And thanks, I´ll look into your answer.

EDIT: You gave me an explanation of how to parse HTML. Like I said, I already know how to parse HTML in several ways. What I need to do is EXECUTE scripts on an external website through my own code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not too sure what the quesiton is.  - If you want to grab a web page from java and then strip out the html data then that is a task that you can fairly easily do - or use something like nutch.  If you want to run the javascript inside a page inside your java then you will need to look at something like rhino.

nutch will spider the pages, and update a database (usually solr) you can then issue searches against the database and display the results.

Comment: A good bit of this should be a comment dude.  In these cases I say something like "I'm not sure you are talking about XXXX."  Then my answer.   Then "If you were talking about something else, edit your question."

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gray - I am a bit new on this site TBH - how do i do a comment - i see on this thread there is a grey Add Comment link, but there is not one under the OP post ?   EDIT - ahh i need a 50 rep to add a comment .